# Ordered Probit R

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying create an ordered probit model in R. My independent variable is categorical, my dependent variable is ordinal. I'm using the polr command and it does go through. When I run the command, I get the log odds for the different variables. I have converted them into odds ratios using the exp command. As far as I understand it, these odds ratios tell me what the probability is of my dependent variable going up one category every time my independent variable "goes up" one category. Is that correct? I'm somewhat confused because in the case of the independent variable, it's not really an increase since they are just categories.

My second question concerns the interpretation of the polr. All I get are the odds ratios. How would you recommend I get additional information on the suitability of the ordered probit? Thanks!

Comment: `polr` does *proportional-odds* fitting; for probit fitting you might consider `ordinal::clm(...,link="probit")` ...

Comment: This sounds more like a CrossValidated.com question (or questions) since you are really asking how to interpret the output from any statistical package that runs proportional odds logistic regression. And as Ben points out you haven't even got your terminology consistent with the methods.

Comment: Thanks! Point taken.